# firestore snapshot of certain documents

Tags: javascript, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

> Any suggestions on how to get a snapshot to only return certain
> documents in a collection?

```html
 db.collection('locations-data').get().then(snapshot => {
      setupLocations(snapshot.docs);
```

The JS setupLocations function loops through and adds data to an ul/li on the UI.It Works but it loads every document and I only want a specific document based on a users access listed in a user collection.

In my "locations-data" collection I have documents named by location (e.g. ca1001, ca1002, etc.)

And a `user collection > userID > locations` array to set which locations a user can view.

As mentioned above, The Setup works great on the front-end but loads all documents and I only want certain users to get certain locations (documents) to show in the UI.

I get the locations array from the users collection into a var, and have tried using map and other things on the code side, also tried a few things via security rules, etc. Just not having much luck.

Here's the code on the UI side that loads the display for the user.

```html
// show locations
const setupLocations = (data) => {
  if (data.length) {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      const location = doc.data();

      const li = `
      <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">
      ${location.shortName}, Total Income: ${location.todayIncome}
      </div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white">${location.totalIncome}</div>
      </li>
    `;
      html += li;
    });
    locationList.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    locationList.innerHTML = '<h5 class="center-align">Login to view data</h5>';
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you tried with 'in' query filter.?

Comment: I did briefly, will work through that option again. I have about 20-30 users and around 20 documents. All having various levels of access needed to each location.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using "array-contains" and just added a users field to each document I want to include. .where('_users', 'array-contains', user.email). Will just have to create a simple admin to manage users this way to avoid having to add all users to each document manually.  Thanks all for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to get a snapshot to only return certain documents in a collection?

Since your first option is to get all document based on the users location you can use what @pepe said, the [where in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) query filter to get a specific or certain documents inside your collection. The other option is store all the data of location from `user` collection to a array variable then display it directly to your UI. With that you don't need to query for `location-data` collection because you already got all the specific location data based on the user's data.